# JSON разбавляется мусором

Tags: json, symfony

Всем привет.

Использую Symfony 5.2. (composer update сделан)

PHP 7.4

Docker контейнер + NGINX.

Есть проблема, которая заключается в том, что контролер отдает не валидный JSON ответ.

Но эта проблема проявляется на проде, локально нет.
И не каждый ответ с поломаным JSON  а периодически, угадать нельзя, может на третий раз, а может на 5-ый, или на 7-ой, но постоянно.
Сам контролер на вход получает JSON строку, и на выходе отдает JSON строку.
Вот аргумент для контролера

```
{order: "22", productType: "2", productId: "64"}
```

Вот что контролер в итоге должен отдать

```
{"order":22,"count":1,"price":5000,"currency":"RUB","cart":[{"id":923,"order":22,"productType":2,"productId":64,"count":1,"created":{"date":"2021-02-03 19:06:39.634912","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}]}
```

А вот что отдает на самом деле

```
{"order":"22","product_type":"2","product_id":"64"}{"order":22,"count":1,"price":5000,"currency":"RUB","cart":[{"id":923,"order":22,"productType":2,"productId":64,"count":1,"created":{"date":"2021-02-03 19:06:39.634912","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}]}
```

То есть в начало почему то добавлен мой аргумент.
Обратите внимание, что после мусорной строки нет запятой, и индексы в этом мусоре выглядят как snake_case, хотя все оставльное содержимое как CamelCase

В начале подумал что может дело в NGINX но там все ок.
Я через утилиту tcpdump проверил что именно отдает PHP контейнер в котором Symfony.

Я так же сохранял в лог данные которые сериализуются (массив), и в логах все ок.

1. Я пишу в лог прям перед отдачей new JsonResponse()
   В лог пишется валидный массив без мусора.
2. Я делал свой EventListener на событие Response с приоритетом -10000 (что бы последниим вызывался) и в нем так же пишу в лог результирующий ответ, и там валидный JSON
3. Я прям в самом главном файле index.php перед ответом скрипта тоже пишу в лог его ответ , и там тоже валидный без мусора JSON

Привожу код контролера
https://pastebin.com/ET0ajy9e

Подскажите куда еще рыть

Comment: Добавьте ещё код функции addProduct у OrderProvider.

Comment: Тот код ничего не прояснит. Ошибка не в коде, ошибка в настройках окружения.
Я перед отдачей  JsonResponse пишу в лог что именно контроллер отдает, и в логах верные данные, а по факту в итоге на выходе из PHP контейнера - данные не верные. Значит проблема не на уровне кода, а выше.